# full index checkbox while creating new database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am creating a new database, which I am basically designing for the logging/history purpose. So, I'll make around 8-10 tables in this database. Which will keep the data and I'll retrieve it for showing history information to the user.

I am creating database from the SQL Server 2005 and I can see that there is a check box of " Use full Indexing". I am not sure whether I make it check or unchecked. As I am not familiar with the database too much, suggest me that by checking it, will it increase the performance of my database in retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is the check box for FULLTEXT indexing.

You turn it on only if you plan to do some natural language queries or a lot of text-based queries.

See here for a description of what it is used to support.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

From that base link, you can follow through to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx (amongst others).  Interesting is this quote

> **Comparison of LIKE to Full-Text Search**
>
> In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works
>   on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to
>   query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large
>   amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent
>   full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions
>   of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text
>   query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending
>   on the number of rows that are returned.

There is a cost for this of course which is in the storage of the patterns and relationships between words in the same record.  It is really useful if you are storing articles for example, where you want to enable searching by "contains a, b and c".  A LIKE pattern would be complicated and extremely slow to process `like %A%B%C% OR LIKE '%B%A%C' Or ...` and all the permutations for the order of appearance of A, B and C.

Comment: Does it make my searching faster than the regular database [which does not have full text search enabled]?  If that is so, what is the disadvantage of using full text search?

Comment: I have edited the answer with more info. Fulltext search is for advanced text-ual searching, not for simple record searching.